# Azure AD identity pass through from the website to the azure sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, azure

I would like to develop solution which is based on the Azure Active Directory identity.

- When the user enters the website it asks them to sign in with their azure active directory login and password.
- The website allows them to fill a form with some information and press "Send"
- After filling the form the user hits "Send" and the data goes to the web api in the backend where the database operation is performed
- The user identity goes through all these layers and reaches the azure sql database
- If they have read\write rights (defined on the db level) the data operation is performed.
- The user signs in only once, after entering the website. The website remembers their identity along the way, and passes it to the backend web api and finally sql database.

Putting it simple: I want to sign in only once with AAD (on the website level), and it will be mapped with the database user when the db operation is performed. I also don't want to sign in each and every time I make a call to the backend.

The website is going to be developed in ASP.NET Core 1.1 and entity framework core.

My main question is, how should I proceed with the user identity part? How should it be passed through and what should be used to store it in the browser?

The second question is, can Entity Framework be used to pass the user identity to the database?

My main concern is that even if I'm able to sign in to the website I create, I will have to sign in again when the request to the database is performed (I might be wrong here).

I found some interesting tutorials to achieve something similar but they talk about a desktop client instead of a website. In my case, there will be one project containing the website and the web api.

I found this 3 part course:

https://msftplayground.com/2017/04/part-1-azure-sql-database-with-azure-active-directory-authentication/

and this one:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/10/20/how-i-connected-a-console-application-to-a-web-api-protected-by-an-azure-active-directory/

Thank you in advance for all of the responses

Answer (score 0):

> My main question is, how should I proceed with the user identity part? How should it be passed through and what should be used to store it in the browser?

It is same as other common web app authenticate with claims. We just need to use the **OAuth 20.0 auth code grant flow** and acquire the token for the Azure SQL database to create an connection(refer [code grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)).

> The second question is, can Entity Framework be used to pass the user identity to the database?

As above mentioned, after authentication we can acquire the access token for Azure SQL database, we can create the connection to the database. And using this connection for the entity frame work. Here is the code create the connection using token:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder["Data Source"] = "aad-managed-demo.database.windows.net"; // replace with your server name
builder["Initial Catalog"] = "demo"; // replace with your database name
builder["Connect Timeout"] = 30;

string accessToken = TokenFactory.GetAccessToken();
if (accessToken == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Fail to acuire the token to the database.");
}
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.AccessToken = accessToken;
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to the database");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

> My main concern is that even if I'm able to sign in to the website I create, I will have to sign in again when the request to the database is performed (I might be wrong here).

There is no need to addition sign-in. As description above, user only need to sign-in once then then can query the Azure SQL database.

And here is helpful blog which contains code sample about token authentication for Azure SQL database:

[Token-based authentication support for Azure SQL DB using Azure AD auth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/02/09/token-based-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-ad-auth/)

Comment: Thank you for the response. The example was very helpful.